# Sequencias do padrão ASCII no vscode (ANSI)

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, ansi

Estou pretendendo migrar do pycharm para o VS Code. Só que tem algo dando vários erros. Algo que era baste como eu usar no pycharm para deixar o texto mais amigável, erra o uso de certas sequências do padrão ASCII, como:

"\033[1m" = negrito

"\033[4m" = sublimado

entres outros (até mesmo mudar a cor do texto e do fundo).

Isso infelizmente não é interpretado pelo terminal do VS Ccode. Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, essas são sequẽncias "ANSI", não "ASCII".
Quanto a sua questão - o problema é do Windows que não habilita essas sequẽncias por padrão - funcionam n Mac, Linux, e outros ambientes, e mesmo no antigo DOS, antes do Windows, era mais fácil ativa-las.

O Pycharm usa um outro terminal próprio dele, e por isso as seqũencias funcionam.

Para habilitar as sequências ANSI no terminal padrão do Windows (o que provavelmente deve funcionar para o terminal usado para o VS Code também), a forma mais fácil é usar a biblioteca terceira chamada "colorama".

Instale-a com pip, `pip install colorama`, e no seu programa Python, coloque essas linhas no início:

```
 import colorama
 colorama.init()
```

Comment: Obrigado, não funciona tão bem quanto no pycharm, mas funcionam. Pelo que eu tava pesquisando isso funciona melhor com o padrão UNIX...